# MultiBinding with StringFormat and localization using VisualBaml

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, locbaml

I am writing a WPF application, which is then translated using `VisualLocBaml`. `VisualLocBaml` works mostly fine and allow me to translate all relevant strings, except for the `StringFormat` I use for a `multibinding`.

Here is the `XAML` portion of the code that has the `multibinding`:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_3" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="24">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding x:Uid="MultiBinding_1" StringFormat="Your ladder position at {0} is {1}">
           <Binding x:Uid="Binding_1" Path="localInfos.Town" />
           <Binding x:Uid="Binding_2" Path="userInfos.Pos" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I tried adding some Localization attribute as described here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753944(v=vs.110).aspx, like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_3" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Localization.Attributes = "$Text(Modifiable Readable)">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding x:Uid="MultiBinding_1" StringFormat="Your ladder position at {0} is {1}" Localization.Attributes = "$StringFormat(Modifiable Readable)">
           <Binding x:Uid="Binding_1" Path="localInfos.Town" />
           <Binding x:Uid="Binding_2" Path="userInfos.Pos" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

But it didn't help: the `StringFormat` "Your ladder position at {0} is {1}" is still the only relevant string that is not available to translate in `Visual LocBaml`